# IPython 3.5 returns "bad interpreter: No such file or directory"

Tags: python, bash, macos, ipython

I am getting random error while trying to use IPython. I now suddenly cannot use iPython3 with no explanation, I don't remember installing anything heavy besides Ethereum client and I didn't download the hashes or anything.  Suddenly I get:

```
cchilders:~ 
$ ipython3
-bash: /usr/local/bin/ipython3: /usr/local/opt/python3/bin/python3.5: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

neither IPython or IPython3 was working. After uninstalling and reinstalling Python and Python3, I can now use IPython. But the same error from before happens if I try iPython3.

This is one of the more absurd errors I've seen because I've reinstalled IPython, Python itself, and Python3 with no change.

Comment: Did you ever figure this problem out?

Comment: I think I just started reinstalling stuff till it worked

Answer (score 28, accepted):

As described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34062502/jupyter-notebook-broken-by-python-3-5), the problem is that ipython3 is trying to use the python3.5 kernel in `/usr/local/opt/python3/bin/python3.5`. You can view which kernel ipython3 is trying to use by running:

```
jupyter kernelspec list
```

and then viewing the `kernel.json` file which is in the python3 kernel's path (in my case, the path to kernel.json is: `/usr/local/share/jupyter/kernels/python3/kernel.json`).

To solve this, I had to reinstall all of the following jupyter packages:

```
$ pip3 uninstall jupyter jupyter-client jupyter-console jupyter-core
$ pip3 install jupyter jupyter-client jupyter-console jupyter-core
```

Comment: The most complete and clearest answer I've come across online. +1!

Comment: I was getting the error described in the question when launching Spacemacs with the `python` layer. I did not have `jupyter` installed, and running the second command fixed the issue for me.

Comment: Did not solve the problem for me. I still get `bash: /home/user/.local/bin/ipython: /usr/local/bin/python: bad interpreter: No such file or directory` error.

Answer (score 2):

If you are not a Jupyter user, this can be solved by reinstalling ipython

```
pip uninstall ipython
pip install ipython
```

I found that I needed `sudo` to uninstall it due to some additional errors. You may not need it.

Answer (score 1):

For me, the wrong version of jupyter was being invoked.  When I was just typing Jupiter, it was looking for installation under 3.7 while it was really installed under the 3.8 directory.

Uninstalling and reinstalling did not help for me.  Instead, I had to give the absolute path to the 3.8 version of Jupiter to get past this error.

Answer (score 0):

what I did was to change the hardcoded python version in  `/usr/local/bin/ipython3`

```
#!/usr/local/opt/python/bin/python3.9 #<--- here, it was 3.7
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
import sys
from IPython import start_ipython
if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.argv[0] = re.sub(r'(-script\.pyw|\.exe)?$', '', sys.argv[0])
    sys.exit(start_ipython())
```

you might have to do the same for `/usr/local/bin/jupyter-notebook` too. And setting up PATH is also important: 
`export PATH=$PATH:/Users/<user>/Library/Python/3.9/bin/`