# How to resolve `/usr/local/opt/python/bin/python3.7 bad interpreter: No such file or directory` for jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I tried to start `jupyter notebook` the way I have been for a long time, and I get the following output:

`$jupyter notebook`

`bash: /usr/local/bin/jupyter:  /usr/local/opt/python/bin/python3.7: bad interpreter: No such file or directory`

Upon inspiration from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43701835/) I discovered that the file `/usr/local/bin/jupyter` contained a path to `/usr/local/opt/python/bin/python3.7`, which was a nonexistent file.  So, I changed the path to the following `/usr/local/bin/python3.10` at the first line of `/usr/local/bin/jupyter`, so it looks like this:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3.10 

import re 

import sys 

from jupyter_core.command import main 

if __name__ == '__main__': 

    sys.argv[0] = re.sub(r'(-script\.pyw|\.exe)?$', '', sys.argv[0]) 

    sys.exit(main())
```

This seemed like a promising solution to me.  However, when I run `jupyter notebook` again, I’m getting the following output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 

  File "/usr/local/bin/jupyter", line 5, in <module> 

    from jupyter_core.command import main 

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'jupyter_core'
```

However, none of the solutions listed at https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/3464 were able to resolve this for me.

Finally, I tried reinstall jupyter via `pip3 install jupyter`, but it’s giving me a legacy install error for `libxml2` (happy to share details on that if they’re relevant).

Am I missing an easier way to resolve this issue with jupyter notebook? Or do I need to modify this path in other files as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uninstalling via brew, and overwriting the existing jupyter notebook files worked:

`brew uninstall jupyter`
`brew link --overwrite jupyterlab`

Still no resolution on why `pip3 install jupyter` didn't work.